# Requesting styled Google Map tiles via URL

Tags: api, maps, style, google

I'm not working with the Google Maps API but I'd still like to be able to request styled map tiles. Is it possible to request a styled Google Map tile via a URL similar to the slippy map URL format for OSM, eg:
http://[abc].tile.cloudmade.com/your_CloudMade_API_key/2/256/zoom/x/y.png

The '2' in the URL above represents the map style ID. I'm not sure if there's any such identifier in the Google Maps API?

Thanks for any advice.
Ed Saunders

Comment: Where do you want to use these styled tiles? In Leaflet?

Comment: If you need just a few tiles, you could use the Static API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps

Comment: Thanks for your input Devdatta. I'm using Geocortex Essentials and I've been able to add custom tiled layers (including Google Maps, OSM, Nearmap, MapQuest etc) using the standard slippy map URL format. I can't see any way to do this to dynamically request styled Google tiles. I think you have to use the Google map object. I'll see how I go with the static API. Thanks again.